# Skilling Mack vs Mixed Effect - Which statistical analyses should I use?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have repeated measures variable data (with 3 timepoints) and 3 different outcomes. Each outcome group is of varying sizes and there is missing variable data. The distribution of the variable data are generally non-normal and also between the outcome groups, heteroscedastic.

I've read around and thought that Skilling Mack is the test I should be using, but my supervisor said it should be mixed effect (he doesn't know Skilling Mack). I've read about mixed effect and it seems to be used more for modelling?

Should I use mixed effect or skilling mack, and what's the difference?

- EDIT (01)

Research question is whether certain variables can predict severity of disease (mild, moderate, severe). The study is a longitudinal study, so there are repeated measures. The repeated measures were conducted on different days of illness which further complicated the analysis, but I've grouped them into phases of illness.

The variables that are giving problems are continuous, non-normal and have different distributions across the different outcomes. Examples of a variable will be something like cardiac output.

Comment: What is your research question ? Please explain your study design and describe all the variables.